# Null object returned when fetching from Shippo API

Tags: javascript, shippo

I'm trying to get a list of all my shipments from the Shippo API. I'm using the fetch() API to get the data.

This is my code:

```
fetch("https://api.goshippo.com/shipments/", {
  method: "GET",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `ShippoToken ${shippoToken}`
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Can't access url");
  });
}
```

Here is a picture of what's happening in the console :

[image]

I'm getting a valid response but the object returned from the response's JSON has null next, null previous, and an empty array of results even though I have shipments in my account. I'm currently using a shippo_test token as my shippoToken.

Comment: What result do you get in Postman?

Comment: What does the response look like if you send the request in something like Postman? That would narrow the issue down to API usage vs javascript problems.

Comment: Ah, empty array, is just because there are not any matching results.

Comment: This is my response on Postman, https://i.imgur.com/J5Ls9qm.png. I'm not sure why I'm getting 401, I'm using the same token. @Alicia

Comment: Fixed the problem by using the live token instead of the test token

Comment: I think that shot from PostMan is pretty self-explanitory. You are missing your token, correct that, then update your question accordingly.